# How to let QRadioButton show focus border correctly

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to fix focus issue on my qt project.

What I have:
[image]

What I need:
[image]

I do not need border around circle and I need to fix right margin.
Please do not worry about concrete text inside of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove / change the selection border using QSS:

```
QRadioButton:focus {
    border: none; /* or your modified border here */
}
```

Comment: Added qApp->setStyleSheet("QRadioButton:focus { border: none; }"); before ui initialization, I have no effect.

Comment: Here is style for radiobutton. Discovered it a minute ago:  "QRadioButton::indicator {"
      "  width: 16px;"
      "  height: 16px;"
      "}" Rest are just image to state assignments.

Comment: If I drop this custom style sheet, everything works ok, so it just overwrites correct focus style with my custom one. Right now I do not know how can I get default radio button style sheet to check what properties it drops.

Comment: Just logged stylesheet before custom style sheet assignment. Default stylesheet is empty string. Not sure what to do next.